# Male lead is last human surviving, who gets killed and reincarnated back to when he's a child

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The manga is about a mage guy who is the last man surviving with his parallel casting ability however using this ability need him to stay still.

He died in the end but before he dies he met the heroine who gives him his acceleration ability.

He is reincarnated back to his childhood, and during that time he starts attending academy at the 10th room (last rank room) because of his parallel ability is deemed inferior.

I think he is one of the few attending with a proficiency of lightning exceeding 80 and water around 75, and can transform his body into lightning.

The manga should be from Chinese (I remember it is full color).

- There is a loli headmaster that is a water god tier and one of the seven mages of the kingdom.
- Another one of the seven mages of the kingdom is a homosexual with wind god tier.
- The female lead is the descendent of the heroine who gave the MC his acceleration ability. The FL has a complication in her family because they want to marry her to another powerful family to allow the bloodlines to mix and produce the strongest passive ability.
- I think ML also has a partner which is a princess knight at a higher year in the school.

I remember that the later part of the manga is about a school tournament. It is a pair tournament (mage and knight) but the protagonist attends it solo as a mage.

In the semi-final, he fights against a female student that uses a flail as a weapon and in the final he fights with the female lead. In the end, this exposes that he has a god tier lightning attunement.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the character art or specific locales?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/p241ke/help_finding_manga_thanks/ - Your question (on Reddit) seems to be nearly identical. Have you not thought of anything additional to add in the last couple of days?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @SaintTail - Was this full colour, or mostly black & white?

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestion. I edited my answer to include all the information I can remember. I also delete that reddit sub since having it in multiple places is not good. At first, I don't know where should I ask.

Comment: Versatile Mage ?? Is it so many content that I may have forgot

Comment: @someoneuseless Not Versatile Mage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find out what I'm been asking. It is actually a **Thai Novel** name *Magic X Knight REVERSE*, not a manga or manhua.

I am very sorry that my memory was maybe mixed up and I thought I read a manhua.

The novel is about Xes the garbage magician, who no one wants as a partner, who happens to be the last man standing in a world infested with monsters. He is being sent back in time by the spirit of the heroine to solve the problem of the monsters.

Here is the [link](https://writer.dek-d.com/Thanabodee33088/writer/view.php?id=2174560) for those of you who are interested.

Comment: It's okay if it's not a manga, but please add the title and details of what it is so the question can help future searchers.